# How to create variable names on the fly

Tags: c, database, struct, naming

How does one create C variable names on the fly? Can it be done? This is more tricky than I previously imagined.

My specific case is this:

- I am creating *n* arrays, where *n* is user input.
- I would like them to be named something like: { a1, a2, a3... a *n* }

Obviously, it is easy to make array *contents* on the fly, but to *name* the arrays on the fly seems tricky. I honestly don't even have an approach right now. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What are you **actually** trying to do? This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: You can't. That's not how programming works.

Comment: More specifically, why do you think you need to know the names of the variables?

Comment: @KerrekSB actually, for plenty of languages that is *exactly* how programming works.

Comment: @KerrekSB Don't look at the implementation of `object_getInstanceVariable();`, you'll lose your virginity.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: How so? If I give you a file containing names, how will you make variables with that name? And no, I don't consider triply indirected Bash evals as "programming" :-) (I.e. it's not a technique of central idiom in that language.)

Comment: What about PHP or Python?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Again, that's not what you'd idiomatically do in those languages, either. Yes, they have "eval", but you don't structure programs with that.

Comment: Even in PHP, variable variables are bad.

Comment: @KerrekSB I never said it was a good idea, I was just saying that's how the languages work :-)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Yes, that's how the languages work, but that's not how *programming* works :-)

Comment: PS: ever heard of autohotkey? Let's just say it doesn't have arrays but it does have variable variables and some namespace guidelines ;-)

Comment: The way I name variables on the fly is to just think of an appropriate name, and type it in the source code. I can't imagine what else you actually mean.

Comment: @KerrekSB: In Python you don't need eval. Leaving aside some caveats about what happens when a name exists in multiple scopes, `foo = 1;` in a function is more or less equivalent to `locals()['foo'] = 1;` or `key = 'fo' + 'o'; locals()[key] = 1;`. That you and I think variables are in some way different from string keys in a hashmap is an artifact of our C-based upbringing, it's nothing to do with "programming" per se ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make C variables after the program has been compiled. In order to create named *things* at runtime you need a dynamic data structure like a dictionary.

That said, perhaps you don't actually need the variables named, in which case a dynamically allocated array is what you need. Since you cannot actually create variables at runtime, the naming issues becomes moot.

Comment: Awesome. I will probably melt my core messing around with that, but that is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like you just need another dimension on your array... Or something like that, at least.

Comment: Yes, your answer from earlier was a great idea, but I had trouble implementing it. Still working on it, I suppose...!

Answer (score 2):

Well, seems like you need to redesign your code if you really need a terrible hack like this. Or did you just want to **index** the array?

```
int arr[128];

int foo = array[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

No. Variable names (and types, and so on) are erased once a C program is compiled.

Answer (score 1):

In C, variable names are a compile time thing, not a runtime one. They are usually replaced with memory addresses and offsets when you compile your code.

However, it looks to me like what you're trying to create is an array of arrays. In that scenario, `a` would be an array of arrays and every `a[n]` would be an array of its own.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create new variable names at runtime.

Anytime you say something like "I need N things named a1, a2, a3, ... aN", what you're really asking for is an array of things: `a[N]`.  In this case, you say you want N arrays named a1, a2, a3...aN, so what you are really asking for is an array of arrays: `a[N][M]`.

Assuming the size of each array is known at compile time, and all you need are the number of those arrays, this becomes easy:

```
#define M 10 // size of each array

int (*arrs)[M];  
size_t numArrs;

printf("Gimme the number of arrays:  ");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%zu", &numArrs);

arrs = malloc(sizeof *arrs * numArrs);
```

At this point you can use `arrs` as a regular 2D array:

```
arrs[i][j] = some_value();
printf("a[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, arrs[i][j]);
```

etc.  When you're done with it, be sure to free the array:

```
free(arrs);
```

Note that this example has nothing resembling error handling; you will want to test the results of the `scanf` and `malloc` calls for sure.

Comment: @d0rmLife: if `malloc` fails, it will return NULL.  So test `arrs` against NULL: `if (arrs == NULL) { // malloc failed }`.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your tolerance of my skill level.

Answer (score 1):

This is really the same as John Bodes answer, but with a complete code example.

John Bode wrote:

> You cannot create new variable names at runtime.
>
> Anytime you say something like "I need N things named a1, a2, a3, ... aN", what you're really asking for is an array of things: a[N]. In this case, you say you want N arrays named a1, a2, a3...aN, so what you are really asking for is an array of arrays: a[N][M].
>
> Assuming the size of each array is known at compile time, and all you need are the number of those arrays, this becomes easy:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARRAY_DEPTH 3
int main( int argc, char * argv[])
{
  if( argc != 2 )
  {
    fprintf(stderr,"%s: Usage %s <number of arrays>\n",
        argv[0], argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  int i,j;
  int n = atoi(argv[1]);
  int (*arrays)[ARRAY_DEPTH];
  arrays = malloc(sizeof(int)*n*ARRAY_DEPTH);

  /* Do your stuff */

  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    for(j = 0; j < ARRAY_DEPTH; j++) 
    {
      fprintf(stderr,"%3d,",arrays[i][j]);
    }
    fprintf(stderr,"\n");
  }
  free( arrays);
  return 0;
}
```

Outputs

```
$ ./narray 5
0,  0,  0,
0,  0,  0,
0,  0,  0,
0,  0,  0,
0,  0,  0,
```

Comment: Does the `(*arrays)` have to be written as it is in `int (*arrays)[ARRAY_DEPTH];`? Is `int* (arrays)[ARRAY_DEPTH];` equivalent? My value types are abstract data types rather than `int`'s, so I am wondering what the proper sytnax would be...

Comment: Never mind, I discovered the answer. The working example you provided was **HELPFUL**. Thanks!